# Stop jquery countdown reset on page refresh?

Tags: jquery

I found [this](https://harshen.github.io/jQuery-countdownTimer/) awesome plugin but unfortunately, the author doesn't provide support anymore. I know I'm not helping much, I'm not a js pro, but is there any way we could stop the countdown reset on every page refresh? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Edit: By stop, I mean running once until will expire or until I'll click a stop or refresh button, the same remaining duration for everybody, just like using the format **dateAndTime : "2022/01/01 00:00:00"**

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/534jy27o/1/)

```
<div id="clock"></div>

$(function(){
   $("#clock").countdowntimer({
      size : "lg",
      hours : 24,
      minutes : 10,
      displayFormat : "DHMS",
      labelsFormat : true
   });
});
```

Comment: by stop you mean run it `once` and once page is refreshed do not run it again for that user ?

Comment: Or do you mean: each time you refresh the page it resets the countdown and you don't want the countdown to reset?

Comment: Yes, I mean running once and stop only if I'll hit a refresh/stop button or until will expire.

Answer (score 0):

To retain the countdown values on page refresh you need to use the `dateAndTime` property so that the countdown is calculated against a static date, instead of adding 24 hours and 10 minutes to the *current* date. Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $("#clock").countdowntimer({
    size: "lg",
    dateAndTime : "2020/09/03 12:00:00",
    displayFormat: "DHMS",
    labelsFormat: true
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/harshen/jQuery-countdownTimer/master/dist/js/jQuery.countdownTimer.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/harshen/jQuery-countdownTimer/master/dist/css/jQuery.countdownTimer.css" />
<div id="clock"></div>
```

Comment: Yes I tried that but I need the format I posted instead cause it's much simpler than calculating the duration every time.

Comment: So you want it so that when user 1 opens the page at 10am on Monday it expires at 10:10 Tues, but if user 2 opens the page at 10:30am on Monday, it expires for them at 10:40 Tues?

Comment: No, the duration should be calculated from the moment I'll create it. If I'll create the countdown now at 10:58, for 1h, all users should see the same remaining duration.

Comment: You would need to do that server side for it to be recognised by all clients.